# url with id not turning to friendly urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a custom PHP CMS website.

```
https://example.com/
```

I have been able to remove the `.php` extension for `https://example.com/archives` for example.

But when it comes to:

```
https://example.com/single-article.php?getid=1425
```

I have tried EVERYTHING the code just won't change in the `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^single-article/([0-9]+)/([09-9a-zA-Z_0]+) single-article.php?getid=$1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the HTAccess recipe you wrote is working

Comment: I see, how can I do it so that it become:
mrvsa.com/single-article/1345 as an example?

Comment: We can do this step by step, i've posted an answer below. Let me know what do you see  in the url?

Comment: Hi @FreedomPride, sure can do step by step where is the code?

Comment: The structure looks like having two captures, but you reference only one (the first).

Comment: Maybe just wording, but... "how can I do it so that it become: `example.com/single-article/1345` as an example?" - you don't do that in `.htaccess`; you do that in your application by physically changing the actual links. You use `.htaccess` to then make the _pretty_ URLs "work".

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual URLs you are requesting. ie. the URL that needs to be rewritten in `.htaccess`. `/single-article.php?getid=1425` is presumably the target URL, not the URL being requested. I'm _guessing_ you want to request a URL of the form `/some-article/1425`? However, the rule you posted appears to be expected two additional path segements, not one?